# Multi channel functionality to record mp3 file in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, xamarin.forms

I want to have a functionality of recording a conversation between two person. I want to do it in a such a way that the outgoing sound be on 1 channel and incoming sound on another channel. So finally i get a stereo file(mp3) file having 2 channels.

For now I am looking to achieve this is windows form and then eventually target xamarin.forms(android, iOS, windows).

Any way to achieve this in c#? Or any plugin available for this?

Comment: Dear @Arti, please see [ask]. You are basically asking _us_ to do the research for _you_. It seems as if you have not taken any effort to solve the problem by yourself. Just start your research, prove that you've tried to solve the problem by your own means and if you're stuck we'll happily answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG is a good tool for video or audio manipulation. I've only used it with video, but looks like it can encode two audio channels. Have a look at
[this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation), hope it is helpful